# ARMAX stationarity - Do the exogenous variables need to be stationary too?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, armax

It concerns the ARMAX time series modelling.

In order to have a stationary time series, does the exogoneous part need to be stationary too ? Or it does not have any influence ?

Thank you all !

Comment: Yes, for stationarity the "X" part of ARMAX needs to be stationary.